# Constraining type in Typescript generic to be one of several types

Tags: typescript, generics, discriminated-union

I'm trying to constrain the input of a generic to be one of several types. The closest notation I've found is using union types. Here is a trivial example:

```
interface IDict<TKey extends string | number, TVal> { 
    // Error! An index signature parameter type must be 
    // a 'string' or a 'number'
    [key: TKey]: TVal; 
}

declare const dictA: IDict<string, Foo>;
declare const dictB: IDict<number, Foo>;
```

What I'm looking for, in this example, is a way to say that `TKey` should be either `string` or `number`, but not the union of them.

Thoughts?

Note: This is a specific case of a broader question. For example, I have another case where I have a function that accepts `text` which can be either a `string` or `StructuredText` (parsed Markdown), transforms it, and returns exactly the corresponding type (not a subtype).

```
function formatText<T extends string | StructuredText>(text: T): T {/*...*/}
```

Technically I could write that as an overload, but that doesn't seem like the correct way.

```
function formatText(text: string): string;
function formatText(text: StructuredText): StructuredText;
function formatText(text) {/*...*/}
```

An overload also proves problematic, because it won't accept a union type:

```
interface StructuredText { tokens: string[] }

function formatText(txt: string): string;
function formatText(txt: StructuredText): StructuredText;
function formatText(text){return text;}

let s: string | StructuredText;
let x = formatText(s); // error
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where the `T` type parameter is declared.  I'm guessing something got left out when you pasted the code?

Comment: [Probably relevant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13398).

Comment: Do you want any or all of these to give an error?  `IDict<string | number, Foo>`,  `IDict<'foo' | 'bar', Foo>`,  `IDict<0 | 1 | 2, Foo>`, `IDict<0 | 'foo',Foo>`

Comment: @Amy `TKey` and `TVal` are in the generic part of the declaration of `IDict`. There is no `T`. Did I miss what you are referring to?

Comment: @jcalz My intent is that all of those would be valid cases; perhaps the second case I noted (`function formatText...`) will clarify my intent.

Comment: Also relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094

Comment: @artem Exactly the issue I was trying to describe. It's good to know there is already a conversation surrounding it even if the feature doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @bjnsn its been fixed in an edit

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what you want.  If none of my examples should error, then you don't want an exclusive union; you just want a regular inclusive union, which TypeScript provides.  The `formatText()` example doesn't seem to change that.  If you really want an exclusive union, there should be some code which would be valid for an inclusive union which you want to be an error.  Could you edit the question with some code you'd like to see error?  Or, put another way: `formatText()` looks fine to me the way you have it; what  *specifically* about it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I confused myself and merged two related issues together together. 1) For `IDict` I would love to use an inclusive union (as written). It just errors in Typescript, and that could be solved using an exclusive union. 2) For `formatText`, I'm looking to have it take a string or StructuredText and return that type (but not, for example a subtype of StructuredText). The reason is I'm unwrapping and re-wrapping StructuredText to accomplish the formatting, so a subtype of StructuredText wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 31):

Updated for TS3.5+ on 2019-06-20

#### Issue #1: `K extends string | number` for the index signature parameter:

Yeah, this can't be done in a very satisfying way.  There are a few issues.  The first is that TypeScript only recognizes two direct index signature types: `[k: string]`, and `[k: number]`.  That's it.  You can't do (edit the following is [no longer true](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures) as of TS4.4) <strike>a union of those (no `[k: string | number]`), or</strike> a subtype of those (no `[k: 'a'|'b']`), <strike>or even an alias of those: (no `[k: s]` where `type s = string`)</strike>.

The second issue is that `number` as an index type is a weird special case that doesn't generalize well to the rest of TypeScript.  In JavaScript, all object indices are converted to their string value before being used.  That means that `a['1']` and `a[1]` are the same element.  So, in some sense, the `number` type as an index is more like a subtype of `string`.  If you are willing to give up on `number` literals and convert them to `string` literals instead, you have an easier time.

If so, you can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to get the behavior you want.  In fact, there is a type called `Record<>` that's [included in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.7.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1357) that is exactly what I'd suggest using:

```
type Record<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
};

type IDict<TKey extends string, TVal> = Record<TKey, TVal>
declare const dictString: IDict<string, Foo>; // works
declare const dictFooBar: IDict<'foo' | 'bar', Foo>; // works
declare const dict012: IDict<'0' | '1' | '2', Foo>; // works
dict012[0]; // okay, number literals work
dict012[3]; // error
declare const dict0Foo: IDict<'0' | 'foo',Foo>; // works
```

Pretty close to working.  But:

```
declare const dictNumber: IDict<number, Foo>; // nope, sorry
```

The missing piece getting `number` to work would be a type like `numericString` defined like

```
type numericString = '0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7' // ... etc etc
```

and then you could use `IDict<numericString, Foo>` which would behave like you want `IDict<number, Foo>` to.  Without a type like that, there's not much point trying to force TypeScript to do this.  I'd recommend giving up, unless you have a very compelling use case.

#### Issue #2: Generics that can be widened to a type from a list:

I think I understand what you want here.  The idea is that you'd like a function that takes an argument of a type that extends a union like `string | number`, but it should return a type which is widened to one or more of the elements of that union.  You're trying to avoid an issue with subtypes.  So, if the argument is `1`, you don't want to commit to outputting a `1`, just a `number`.

Before now, I'd say just use overloads:

```
function zop(t: string): string; // string case
function zop(t: number): number; // number case
function zop(t: string | number): string | number; // union case
function zop(t: string | number): string | number { // impl
   return (typeof t === 'string') ? (t + "!") : (t - 2);
}
```

This behaves how you'd like:

```
const zopNumber = zop(1); // return type is number
const zopString = zop('a'); // return type is string 
const zopNumberOrString = zop(
  Math.random()<0.5 ? 1 : 'a'); // return type is string | number
```

And that's the suggestion I'd give if you just have two types in your union.  But that could get unwieldy for larger unions (e.g., `string | number | boolean | StructuredText | RegExp`), since you need to include one overload signature for every nonempty subset of elements from the union.

Instead of overloads we can use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316):

```
// OneOf<T, V> is the main event:
// take a type T and a tuple type V, and return the type of
// T widened to relevant element(s) of V:
type OneOf<
  T,
  V extends any[],
  NK extends keyof V = Exclude<keyof V, keyof any[]>
> = { [K in NK]: T extends V[K] ? V[K] : never }[NK];
```

Here is how it works:

```
declare const str: OneOf<"hey", [string, number, boolean]>; // string
declare const boo: OneOf<false, [string, number, boolean]>; // boolean
declare const two: OneOf<1 | true, [string, number, boolean]>; // number | boolean
```

And here's how you can declare your function:

```
function zop<T extends string | number>(t: T): OneOf<T, [string, number]>;
function zop(t: string | number): string | number { // impl
   return (typeof t === 'string') ? (t + "!") : (t - 2);
}
```

And it behaves the same as before:

```
const zopNumber = zop(1); // 1 -> number
const zopString = zop('a'); // 'a' -> string
const zopNumberOrString = zop(
  Math.random()<0.5 ? 1 : 'a'); // 1 | 'a' -> string | number
```

Whew.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEHkDsFNwMwDwBUA0oBqA+UBLAzqAC4AW0oAtgIY6SjQBu0khAXAFAhGUDWZlRATwAOZJKEqQAJuKIBXIQBsyhYWXRoJ0gE7RCsrbRLLVoAPZwOYMQHcckptGmFToHUvoTCdJeSaEAFHgAlGZwGOwqIhAw8AhsoKCo8Rh0AB6ETJIEEgIA2gC6KMkAcgDSaRlSBLwC5ikAvKAAoqkAxgqy9gg1deqgPWE5BZhs2I0A3qC55TSgZfksiRWZBOjT+aAA-BjroIswjFqgAL658wDcbGz27ZQ6oK2mkHheL1qLULCIAESkAt9oXJvGgAczQkFk5AARtAtGgoaZTEoJPlMOdQJxgZAQddoLd7o9nl4EaYPjFEHBKAo8NBAViwaAIdDYfDEcjIKj0ZwSezcfiyISXkRrKTol8EABGUAAHyIWlktKm9PBkJhcNAPOgKLRGLATLVMo1bK1kCucFkkFahBwT1AAC9TEJkMsqqB6Yb9bDMP5WIkgmTxaglYQtKCVcytJy2ObLdbbQ6hD7Fu7ZZ6tP63SHQR7VbDQJNODhyIpkq5dPpaD7VHUvPU66AAOT0hshbY+0AAalA3wAhN8Qot2wBaUAAJiCl2OV0FXgTxVzR0aCf8EonutAUqH2DTbBn9sdAGUs9jQEvHf4G5QW1ywJeG6At5nQ9jd08hXOF+AtEfnyDT-vE2SABZSgSAAOi0TRTHIfwggQAAGMCAFYtg3PZGyvNdOClWU7wfbAU0ZBcgA)

Comment: The OneOf does not work in tsc@3.5.2: `error TS2344: Type 'keyof V' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: @k0pernikus I updated the code to work.  The problem was that TS2.9 [introduced `number` and `symbol` as key types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types) and this broke some code from TS2.8- which relied on `keyof XXX` being assignable to `string`.