# How to compose union type in a generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, conditional-types

Let's have the following simplified example:

```
type AB = {
    foo: "A"
    bar: "A"
} | {
    foo: "B"
    bar: "B"
}

type Foo = AB["foo"]

function fun<F extends Foo>(foo: F, bar: Extract<AB, { foo: F }>["bar"]) {
    fun2({
        foo,
        bar,
    })
}

function fun2(ab: AB) {

}
```

It fails with: *Argument of type '{ **foo: "A" | "B"**; bar: "A" | "B"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AB'.*

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA3gKCpqAzA9rgLigCIZiMsAjAQwCcjTyBfKAH1Qsz0JLnKyg16vZmjShIUAGL4ksOAG1i3YgF0x2AK4A7AMbAAlrm04dAHilQIAD2ARtAEwDO0-AD4AFNyJSANILoiAFFbWmp9M3h-FBx8HygmNyUhNQBKDgEtbQAmD3QBTPxfTgKhYoEmVLQmDR19IxMs3OpKInh09Gq0IA)

1. How to restrict the generic type not to accept union types?

   - @jcalz answers a similar question here [Constraining type in Typescript generic to be one of several types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49242232/121968). But the answer requires passing all "simple types" to a tuple type.
   - @jcalz then discourages to use his solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/121968 to convert union type to tuple type.
2. And then how to prevent `bar: Extract<AB, { foo: F }>["bar"]` to return union type?

   - `fun<F extends "A">` [will fail](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA3gKCpqAzA9rgLigCIZiMsAjAQwCcjTyBfKAH1Qsz0JLnKyg16vZmjShIUAGL4ksOAG1i3YgF0x2AK4A7AMbAAlrm04dAHilQIAD2ARtAEwDOJMgD4AFNyJSANILoiAFFbWmp9M3h-FBx8HygmNyUhNQBKDgEtbQAmD3QBTPxfTgKhYoEmVLQmDR19IxMs3OpKInh09Gq0IA) with *Argument of type '{ **foo: F**; bar: "A" | "B"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AB'.*

     (Btw. why ***foo: F*** and not just ***foo: "A"*** ?)
   - But `bar: Extract<AB, { foo: "A" }>["bar"]` [will work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA3gKCpqAzA9rgLigCIZiMsAjAQwCcjTyBfKAH1Qsz0JLnKyg16vZmjShIUAGL4ksOAG1i3YgF0x2AK4A7AMbAAlrm04dAHilQIAD2ARtAEwDOJMgD4AFNyJSANILoiAFFbWmp9M3h-FBx8BjIoJjclITUASg4BLW0AJg90ASz8X05CoRKBJjS0Jg0dfSMTbLzqSiJ4DPQatCA).

Comment: @wonderflame It seems to me, that your type Args can be just replaced with AB.

Comment: Yeah..., just realized that, sorry. Do you exactly need the `(foo, bar)` separated?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, I could directly call `fun2`. (In the real situation, `fun` prepares args for `fun2` that gets complex object.)

Comment: I don't think this is possible without an assertion.

Comment: I agree with @zenly. The closest that I could get is in [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpxxam)

Comment: @wonderflame Why you need to define the `Args` type in your solution? (If you are using `as`.)

Comment: I think this is more straightforward for typing the arguments of `fun` rather than doing them with generic.

Comment: @wonderflame Ok, just a matter of personal preference :)